# Questions in the song "Por fin te encontré"

Tags: gramática, letras-de-canciones

In the song *"Por fin Te Encontré"*, they sing:

> Si tu supieras lo que te he esperado
>   *(If you knew that I've been waiting for you)*

Why do they say **"lo que"** instead of **"que"** there?

Doesn't it translate to:

> "If you knew **what** I've waited for you" with **"lo que"**?

Later in the song, they sing:

> Si tu a mi lado vas a tener al que más te adora
>   *(If you are by my side you'll have the one that most adores you)*

Why **"al"** instead of **"el"**?

Wouldn't *"tener al"* translate to:

> "have ***to*** the one" or something like that?

Towards the end, they sing:

> Y yo lo puedo ver, dime qué vas a hacer
>   *(And I can see it, tell me what you gonna do)*

Why **"qué"** (or "que") instead of **"lo que"**?

*"Qué"* is a question word, and *"que"* means "that". Neither of which make sense here.

Comment: The first sentece I would translate as _"If you knew **how much** I've been waiting for you"_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Si tú supieras lo que te he esperado

I'm afraid "If you knew that I've been waiting for you" isn't a good translation. "Lo" in "lo que" is the article used when the following noun is omitted:

- El aspecto más interesante = lo más interesante

I omitted "aspecto" there because it didn't really add any meaning, and I did so by changing "el" to "lo". Generally, the word omitted isn't really anything, but just a meaningless pronoun:

- Lo que me gusta de ella es que es divertida = *aquello* que me gusta de ella es que es divertida

However, sometimes the word elided *is* a meaningful word, but one than can be perfectly understandable without making it explicit. The example at hand would be one of those cases:

> Si tú supieras lo que te he esperado = si tú supieras el *tiempo* que te he esperado
>   (If you knew how much I've been waiting for you)

Note: In English, "wait" is intransitive (i.e., it can't take a DO), but in Spanish it can. You can say "estuve esperando dos horas", which would translate to "I've been waiting (for) two hours".

---

> Si tú a mi lado vas a tener al que más te adora

Once again, the translation provided is not on point. A better translation would be "If you'll have by my side the one that adores you the most". The sentence is incomplete, I guess because it's lacking a context. "A" from "al" is necessary because in Spanish, both direct and indirect objects require "a" when the object is a person:

- "Vi una película." but "Vi **a** tu hermano."

The preposition is necessary when introducing a person, even though "al que más te adora" is a DO, which generally wouldn't be introduced by "a".

---

> Y yo lo puedo ver, dime qué vas a hacer

You are right "qué" is a question word, just like "what" is. And here you *have* a question, but it's an indirect one:

- ¿A dónde vas? = Quiero saber a dónde vas // Dime a dónde vas
- ¿Qué vas a hacer? = Quiero saber qué vas a hacer // Dime qué vas a hacer

Btw, "Dime lo que vas a hacer" is just as fine as "Dime qué vas a hacer". Only in the former, "lo" would be standing for "aquello" (Dime *aquello* que vas a hacer), and "que" would be a mere linker without any semantic meaning, whereas "qué" in the latter would be a pronoun with full meaning.

Comment: Yo pondría simplemente *if you knew **what** I've waited you*, pero esta construcción en Inglés es rara, y usaría la forma continua *if you knew **what** I've been waiting you = si supieras/supieses lo que he estado esperándote.*

Comment: @Ustanak Nunca he oído "if you knew what I've been waiting you", ni sabía que "what" pudiera intercambiarse por "how much". Si algún nativo lo confirma, actualizo la respuesta.